# A-record redirect and apache virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

Someone redirected his domains A-record to my server. Is there any specific config in virtualhosts? or I can use this like a full domain? (Debian Lenny)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Leave Apache configuration alone, it will serve content out of the default www directory for this domain name.
2. Add his domain in VirtualHosts configuration and it will serve the content from whichever directory you specify.